# Unable to run Python Telegram Bot Package - Error

Tags: python, windows, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Hello StackOverFlow Community.

I am working on a telegram bot but facing the error:

`(stockAlert) PS D:\Development\StockAlert> python .\stockAlertBot.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Development\StockAlert\stockAlertBot.py", line 1, in <module> from telegram.ext.updater import Updater ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.ext.updater'`

- I had worked on the same file on my Mac earlier but when I am trying to run it on a Windows machine it is not working.

Error Message:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6X7k.png)

Here is the list of installed packages:
[package_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxDg4.png)

- OS: Windows 11 Pro
- Python Version: 3.9.15

Your help is appreciated.
Thank you !

Things that I tried:

- Uninstalling and installing the package
- Created a new virtual environment and installing the package
- Rebooting the system

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed version 20.0 of `python-telegram-bot` but your code is written for version <=13.5. Please either upgrade your code to  v20 by reading the [release notes](https://telegra.ph/Release-notes-for-python-telegram-bot-v200a0-05-06) and the [transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0) o install a version of PTB that is compatible with your code base.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telgeram-bot`.

Comment: The standard python example on Telegram documentation is still written for 13.5, I guess that is where the confusion comes from

Comment: Which example are you referring to? Do you have a link?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/tutorial this one, when you select Python: https://gitlab.com/Athamaxy/telegram-bot-tutorial/-/blob/main/TutorialBot.py

Comment: Interesting, hadn't known that. Thanks for the tip! TBF, they do explicitly state the required version, so that's as explicit as you can do it, I guess …

Comment: I don't see where the requirement version is mentioned. Most users would expect that the script provided works with the latest

Comment: It's mentioned in the [readme](https://gitlab.com/Athamaxy/telegram-bot-tutorial/-/tree/main#dependencies-1). The PTB team is currently checking if we can get the code updated

Comment: I dont think anyone would go up one level to open the readme since you are directly directed on that script from the page. Thanks for flagging to the team