# ImportError: cannot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext'

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have installed [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org) like this:

```bash
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

And when I'm trying to do this:

```py
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext' (/home/mobitnlh/virtualenv/db_application/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run Python Telegram Bot Package - Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064123/unable-to-run-python-telegram-bot-package-error)

Answer (score 29):

They made some changes, please see the link https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html

Instead of

```py
from telegram.ext import Filters
```

do

```py
from telegram.ext import filters
```

and instead of `Filters.all` do `filters.ALL`

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

According to their [wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Advanced-Filters), the name is `filters`. So just replace `Filters` with `filters`:

```py
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
```

Answer (score -1):

Removed the Filters class.
you can use directly attributes/classes of the filters module.

Filter classes which are ready for use, e.g Filters.all are now capitalized, e.g filters.ALL

below link is includes all :

https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.7/telegram.ext.filters.html