# Simple python telegram bot does not run

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm working with Python 3 and I wanted to make a simple bot, so I coded this:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

bot = telegram.Bot(token='MY_TOKEN')

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hi there, I'm a simple bot!")

def echo(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=update.message.text)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token='YOUR_API_TOKEN_HERE', use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    echo_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), echo)
    dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
    dispatcher.add_handler(echo_handler)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And when I run this code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User 1\Desktop\telegram-bot\index.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
ImportError: cannot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext' (C:\Users\User 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\__init__.py)
```

This error typically occurs when you are using an outdated version of the python-telegram-bot library, or if there is an issue with your installation.

So I tried running these commands but still faces the same issue:

```
pip install --upgrade python-telegram-bot
pip uninstall python-telegram-bot
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75095107/importerror-cannot-import-name-filters-from-telegram-ext