# from telegram.ext greys out CommandHandler In Visual studio

Tags: python, api, python-telegram-bot

From this script

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
```

CommandHandler is shown without color, When I hover over it it says ""CommandHandler" is not accessedPylance"

I've pip installed the telegram bot.

Also When I try to run it says:

```
main.py", **line 5**, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
ImportError: c**annot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext'** (C:\Users\ds\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\__init__.py)
```

Tried to import telegram Python elements from a library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'Filters' from 'telegram.ext'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75095107/importerror-cannot-import-name-filters-from-telegram-ext)