# AttributeError: module 'telegram.ext.filters' has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python-telegram-bot

states={
MOB_NO: [MessageHandler(filters.text, reply_to)],

},

AttributeError: module 'telegram.ext.filters' has no attribute 'text'

I install pip install python-telegram-bot.

And here we import module.
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters,
ConversationHandler)

When we handle messages it says.

AttributeError: module 'telegram.ext.filters' has no attribute 'text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run Python Telegram Bot Package - Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064123/unable-to-run-python-telegram-bot-package-error)

Answer (score 4):

From version 20 of [python-telegram-bot](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/), the filters library is lowercase and the single filters are written all uppercase.

So until v13.7 we had `Filters.text`, but from v20 it became `filters.TEXT`.

Maybe in your `requirements.txt` file you have `python-telegram-bot>=13.4`, so either you change it to `python-telegram-bot==13.7`, or you need to update your code.

Note that this applies also to the import, until v13.7: from `telegram.ext import Filters` becomes `telegram.ext import filters`.

Source: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are using the latest version package. Downgrade the python-telegram-bot version to 13.7.

```
 pip install python-telegram-bot==13.7 --force-reinstall
```

And use "Filters" with capital F