# TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'type'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```py
def main():
    updater = Updater(bot="Telegram API key", update_queue=my_queue)

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
        RECIPIENT_NAME: [MessageHandler(filters.Text & ~filters.Command, callback=recipient_name)],
        RECIPIENT_NUMBER: [MessageHandler(filters.Text & ~filters.Command, callback=recipient_number)],
        SERVICE: [MessageHandler(filters.Text & ~filters.Command, callback=service)],
        VERIFY_IDENTITY: [MessageHandler(filters.Text & ~filters.Command, callback=verify_identity)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )
```

I am trying to make a telegram bot and keep getting this error in this section of my code: bad operand type for unary ~: 'type'

I tried capitalizing and uncapitalizing "Text" "Command" and "filters" and switched around filters.Text & ~filters.Command.

Comment: heads-up you may have leaked your access token and need to rotate it - it will be visible in the history!

Comment: from the docs, https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Command, `Command` is a class. You may want `filters.Command(False)`. I'm not an expert on this one, so just a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run Python Telegram Bot Package - Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064123/unable-to-run-python-telegram-bot-package-error)